# Is it possible to increase the number of bytes for any datatype?

Tags: c, int

The current size of long int in my system is 4 bytes. Is it possible to increase its size? In case it is not possible how to deal with situations where we need integral data type with specified byte size. The applications include factorial, permutations, combinations etc.

Comment: Thanks to all for suggesting the alternate methods. But I would like to explore how can I define my own datatype.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may find `long long int` larger than 4 bytes. The compiler restricts the size of integer types because of how CPUs work.

For arbitrary size integers you have to use special "bignum" libraries such as [GMP](http://gmplib.org/). You can find more about the subject here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bignum

Answer (score 2):

> how to deal with situations where we need integral data type with
>   specified byte size

Use `stdint.h` types like `uint24_t`, `uint32_t`, `uint64_t`, etc.

Comment: how to include them in my programm ? i guess its some library i need to include ?

Comment: @bubble You have to include `stdint.h` and maybe `inttypes.h`.

Comment: `stdint.h` is part of the C language, unless you're using a C compiler that's outdated by more than 13 years.

Comment: Is there such a thing as `uint24_t`?

Comment: @JoniSalonen Some implementations can have it. None of these types is required by the standard. I have never encountered it but I remember reading about it (or maybe it was just some IRC discussion I was half-following?)

Comment: is there a similar thing for float also ?

Answer (score 1):

On almost every system, `long long` is 8 bytes (64-bit).

Comment: my system has int = long int = 4 bytes. I don't know if long long exists.

Comment: Every C compiler has `long long` (except perhaps on embedded systems).